# My answer was flagged with a post notice as lacking sources. I added some, but the post notice wasn't removed. Why?

Tags: support, flagging, post-notices

[My answer here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/105563/32674) was flagged with a post notice as lacking sources. I added some, taking care to cite reliable sources. But the post notice remains.

What is the issue? Why wasn't the post notice removed?

Comment: Just came across your post. Taken care of. thanks for the edits!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sorry about that; the "post notices" asking for citations notify you when they are added, but nothing in the system notifies anyone when you solve the problem.

Frankly, most people don't bother adding any sources and their post gets downvoted or eventually deleted (frequent users know the rules about citations, so it's usually one-timers that get the notice). Thank you very much for taking the requested action!

In the future, you can "flag for moderator attention"; that's usually how the notices are added in the first place, too: someone flags for a moderator to add the notice.

Comment: To add: If we are reminded after you added some sources we do of course remove the post notice.

Comment: I did not know about the  "flag for moderator attention". Thank you.